# ssh-add insists on passphrase

Tags: ssh, osx-lion

I have a new ssh key problem. I have successfully used them for years with Heroku, Git and other servers so I can login without having to issue a passphrase.

A few weeks ago, I was unable to push a git repository on my machine to my Heroku and it responded with Permission denied (publickey).

Hmm. Everything else but this Heroku function still works. So I

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "newHeroku"
```

with no passphrase (hit return so it would be empty). So I enter:

```
 sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/newHeroku*
```

Then:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/newHeroku.pub
```

Returning return for the passphrase asked it exits without error. The next step is to:

```
 ssh-add /Users/sam/.ssh/newHeroku.pub
```

To verify that it's "live" I enter:

```
 ssh-add -l
```

To which the output is still The agent has no identities. Okay, to eliminate variables, I repeat the key generation process but entering in a passphrase for a new key. I ssh-add the new key and get the "Enter passphrase" as expected. **Now this is why I'm posting here and not on a Heroku blog** because ssh-add fails because the passphrase I used keeps getting rejected. It appears, even though I have no problem with my keys elsewhere, that something is wrong with passphrase because even though I get no errors, I get errors when on the one that expects a passphrase. One question, *should I expect the Passphrase request for ssh-add when I have not generated a passphrase?* It's been suggested that this is a clue and I offer it.

Or maybe I have a poor understanding of what ssh-add is doing. Wouldn't be the first time I asked a stupid Q. Also, I'm on Lion and have updated no system updates in the few weeks of this period except application updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a fellow user was able to look at this and share that using the -K option to ssh-add added my key to the OS X keychain. After that, heroku performs as before and like other keys.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/newHeroku.pub
```

seems wrong to me. You're trying to unlock your public key, whereas you should unlock your private (protected) key. So, try

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/newHeroku
```

if that's indeed the filename of your private key.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ssh-agent is actually running. ssh-add only adds your key to the agent, if the agent is not running it will not work.

You can also checkout http://www.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain which is rather nice tool that adds your ssh and gpg keys to the respective agents upon first launching a shell.

Comment: This seems to back up the answer in that it appears to link the SSH keys with the OS X keychain.